# Why aren't my gamerules being saved?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

One of my worlds, I use `/gamerule doDaylightCycle false` to freeze the day/night cycle.

The problem is, whenever I exit and reload the world, it reverts back to doing the day/night cycle. I have to manually type the command everytime I enter the world.

None of my other worlds have this problem, instead they save the previous gamerule when reloading the world.

Comment: I have done this on one of my worlds, and for some reason it saves, but weather causes the sky to go dark even though no rain is being produced. Next time this happens, type `/weather clear` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know it's a bit outdated but have you tried editing the `level.dat`?
Just download [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/840677-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac/) program and run it. Open the menu `File > Open` and then select the `level.dat` in `C:/Users/[me]/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/[matching mc world]/level.dat`. Then unfold to the followings `Data > GameRules > doDaylightCycle`. Double-click to edit it and enter `false`. Save and start the game.

Answer (score -2):

Try making a hopper clock that goes into a command block that says /gamerule doDaylightCycle false. It will most likely create some lag but it will work I think.   If u don't know how to make a hopper clock: put 2 hoppers facing each other and put 1 item in only 1 hopper and put a comparator going out of the hoppers then u can place a repeater after the comparator and finally the command block. If u want to turn the hopper clock off place a lever on top of one of the hoppers by shift clicking it. I hope I helped!!

Comment: This doesn't really fix the problem, you're just automatically entering the command.

Comment: This will create lag too.